# Conceptual question of Linear Transformations and its eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let's think about a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. And say $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $k \lt n$. Then I want to see if each eigen values of restriction of $T$, $T_u$ to $U$ are eigen values of $T$ and how ? When I asked some fellow students they said that it's true because all the elements of $U$ are also the elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ but I don't see how...can someone help me with a formal proof?

**Note:** This is just something conceptual that I want to have a clear understanding about.

Comment: Can you explain this line "if each eigen values of restriction of $T, T_u$ to $U$ are eigen values of $T$" ?

Comment: @Kolmogorov yes ofcourse...all I wanted to say that is it true that every eigen value of the restriction of $T$ to the subspace $U$ is a eigen value of $T$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linear transformation $T$ need not even fix $U$. Indeed if you consider $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by

$$
T\left(\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x+y\\-x+y\end{pmatrix},
$$
then $T$ does not fix any non-trivial subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore the question of eigenvalues does not make sense.

If, for the sake of argument, we assume that $T(U)\subset U$, then by the definition of eigenvector and eigenvalue, we can see that eigenvalues of $T_u$ is a subset of eigen values of $T$.

Comment: can you elaborate on why the question of eigen values is not valid if T doesn't fix any subspace or if image of any subspace under T is not contained in that particular subspace?

Comment: The definition of eigenvalue and eigenvector is the key here. An eigenvector is a "non-zero" vector v such that T(v)=\lambda \cdot v. This requires both v and T(v) to be scalar multiples of each other, i.e. in the same subspace. This clearly cannot happen if T(U) and U intersect trivially.